# How to match a pattern to a string and extract an int from it

Tags: rust

I'm quite new to Rust, also just a hobbyist, and have been scouring around trying to solve this to no avail.

Imagine you have a folder of STLs with a certain namegiving, for example:

```
file2.stl
[a]_Imalsoafile_x2.stl
however_I_canAlsoBe_a_file_x4.stl
[a]_yep_also_a_file.STL
```

I'm at the point to where I was able to sort them properly and divide them up among the two basic categories, one containing the [a]_ prefixed STLs and the ones not containing them. However for me to advance I need to be able to extract the int from _xINT.stl, if there even is one.

In NodeJS I would do this with the following function, of sorts:

```
    analyzeName(name) {
        let number = 1;
    
        let re = /\_x([0-9])/;
        const results = re.exec(name);
        if ( results ) {
            number = parseInt(results[1]);
        }
    
        return {
            times: number,
            name: name
        };
    };
```

However I'm having a really hard time finding some equivalent to this for Rust.

The real question I'm asking is about how to tackle this problem.

Comment: Is your question how to use regular expressions in general or what specific regular expression to use in this particular case?

Comment: You could say I'm trying to figure out how to best tackle this problem as is. I've been searching std::string::String for a possible way to start at this but I just don't see it.

Comment: So you didn't find https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/, for example?

Comment: This one did indeed show up and I was looking into it, however it is still a question for as to how to 'take' the int from the values. For example the example I've given executes said regex and splits it up whilest the crate as far as I can tell only matches and gives you a bool. Perhaps, also judging by the downvotes, I should try simpler stuff before tackling this problem.

Comment: The regex crate is designed to be zero-cost, i.e. don't pay for what you don't use. So it can return match/doesn't match. but it is also able to capture groups - use [`Regex::captures()`](https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/struct.Regex.html#method.captures). Also all you need is to get the whole match, e.g. `Regex::new(r"\d+").unwrap().find(text)?.as_str()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit to get you started:

```rust
fn analyze_name(name: &str) -> Option<u32> {
    name
        .to_ascii_lowercase()
        .strip_suffix(".stl")?
        .rsplit_once("_x")?
        .1
        .parse()
        .ok()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped a great deal. Curious, where did the .1 come from?

Comment: @LeandroMarceddu It takes the second element of a tuple.